# Align function plots with column values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel file with data columns that contain tens of thousands of values and I want to visualize these values in a 2D-function plot

[image]

The way Excel does it is to orient the x-axis of the plot horizontally, which I don't want, rather I want:

- the x-axis oriented vertically
- the y-axis oriented horizontally
- the spacing of x-values in the plot should be the same as the cell heights

so that there is a direct visual correspondence between the function graph and the data values.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of chart are you using? You can change the X and Y axis in a lot of charts.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I used from the 2D line plot the first one that appears in the upper left corner of the selection menu